# オンラインの交流会に参加した場合にもらえるバッジがあると面白そう

Tags: 機能の要求, 交流会, バッジ

オンサイトの交流会については[「ロボットではない」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/115/not-a-robot)というバッジがあるのですが、コロナ下でオンサイトの交流会はここから 1～2 年に渡っても開きづらいでしょうし、オンライン開催を前提とした別のバッジがあって良いのではと思いつきました。せっかく参加してくださった方に何かしら「ちいさなメダル」的なものをお渡ししたいなという思いがあります。

たとえば交流会後にアンケートを用意して、それに答えてくださった方にバッジ、など如何でしょうか。

ひとつのサイト発信でバッジ追加をお願いするのは難しいでしょうが、フィードバックとして受け止めてくださればと思います。

Comment: MSO で類似の話題が挙がっていました。 - [Will there be any future events for users to earn the Not a Robot badge, or is the badge retired?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405839)

Answer (score 2):

賛同します。
イベントがオンラインでもオフラインでも優劣はないと思いますし、バッジがあればさらに張り合いが出ると思います。

MSOの類似の話題では`Deepfakeではない`バッジ名の案が出ていますが、シンプルに`eイベント`のようなバッジがあれば「良いイベント」に参加したことが分かりやすいのではないでしょうか。

※他に思いついたバッジ名の案は「オンライン参加賞」「記念品.net」「電子の海で会った」「*PCのまえにいた*」(「*いしのなかにいる*」パロディ)などですが、イマイチでした。